# Creating a new column in dask (arrays ,list)

Tags: python, list, numpy, dask, dask-dataframe

What would be the equivalent of transforming this to a dask format

```py
df['x'] = np.where(df['y'].isin(a_list), 'yes', 'no')
```

The `df` will be a dask dataframe with `n` partitions and `a_list` is a just a list of items.

The error I am getting if i just change `np.where`  to `da.where`  ,while using the dask dataframe is that `number of partitions do not match 1 != n`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved without `np`:

```py
df["x"] = df["y"].isin(a_list).map({False: "No", True: "Yes"})
```

Here's a reproducible example:

```py
import dask

df = dask.datasets.timeseries(seed=123)

df["x"] = df["name"].isin(["Bob", "Tim"]).map({False: "No", True: "Yes"})

print(df.head(10))
#                        id      name    x         y
# timestamp
# 2000-01-01 00:00:00  1064     Wendy   No  0.921843
# 2000-01-01 00:00:01   983     Edith   No -0.196625
# 2000-01-01 00:00:02  1028     Alice   No -0.512889
# 2000-01-01 00:00:03  1000       Tim  Yes -0.378292
# 2000-01-01 00:00:04  1022     Wendy   No -0.640633
# 2000-01-01 00:00:05  1024       Bob  Yes  0.664895
# 2000-01-01 00:00:06  1011     Quinn   No  0.940216
# 2000-01-01 00:00:07   971   Norbert   No -0.750241
# 2000-01-01 00:00:08  1035    Hannah   No -0.335760
# 2000-01-01 00:00:09  1041  Patricia   No  0.984533
```